# Parse string containing javascript

Tags: java, regex, rhino

I have a string:

```
2 + 2 = ${2 + 2}
This is a ${"string"}
This is an object: ${JSON.stringify({a: "B"})}
This should be "<something>": ${{
    abc: "def",
    cba: {
        arr: [
            "<something>"
        ]
    }

}.cba.arr[0]}
This should ${"${also work}"}
```

And after parsing it I should get something like that:

```
2 + 2 = 4
This is a string
This is an object: {"a":"B"}
This should be "<something>": <something>
This should ${also work}
```

So I need help implementing it **in Java**, I simply need to get what is between `${` and `}`.

I tried using a regular expression: `\${(.+?)}` but it fails when string inside contains `}`

Comment: regex is not the best choice for nested brackets.

Comment: So what'd you suggest?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: One of the ways is to use recursive regex (which is also not very good, but will be ok if you have not too much nested structures). And also not sure if java regex engine supoorts recursion https://regex101.com/r/pFEV5j/1

Comment: Ye, doesn't work in Java (`java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown inline modifier near index 18`). Also your regex doesn't work when there is a line break between ${ and }

Comment: why regex? why not simply iterate through characters in sequence while tracking state (opened quotes; nested brackets), and splitting string into lists of object, where each object is either a normal string, or template content

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit of testing, I've ended up with this:

```
ScriptEngine scriptEngine = new ScriptEngineManager(null).getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String str = "2 + 2 = ${2 + 2}\n" +
        "This is a ${\"string\"}\n" +
        "This is an object: ${JSON.stringify({a: \"B\"})}\n" +
        "This should be \"F\": ${var test = {\n" +
        "    a : {\n" +
        "        c : \"F\"\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "};\n" +
        "test.a.c\n" +
        "}\n" +
        "This should ${\"${also work}\"}"; // String to be parsed
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
boolean dollarSign = false;
int bracketsOpen = 0;
int beginIndex = -1;
int lastEndIndex = 0;
char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) { // i is for index
    char c = chars[i];
    if(dollarSign) {
        if(c == '{') {
            if(beginIndex == -1) {
                beginIndex = i + 1;
            }
            bracketsOpen++;
        } else if(c == '}') {
            if(bracketsOpen > 0) {
                bracketsOpen--;
            }
            if(bracketsOpen <= 0) {
                int endIndex = i;
                String evalResult = ""; // evalResult is the replacement value
                try {
                    evalResult = scriptEngine.eval(str.substring(beginIndex, endIndex)).toString(); // Using script engine as an example; str.substring(beginIndex, endIndex) is used to get string between ${ and }
                } catch (ScriptException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                result.append(str.substring(lastEndIndex, beginIndex - 2));
                result.append(evalResult);
                lastEndIndex = endIndex + 1;
                dollarSign = false;
                beginIndex = -1;
                bracketsOpen = 0;
            }
        } else {
            dollarSign = false;
        }
    } else {
        if(c == '$') {
            dollarSign = true;
        }
    }
}
result.append(str.substring(lastEndIndex));
System.out.println(result.toString());
```